# Why my CPU of 2.1GHz clocks at 800mhz in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: hardware, intel, cpu

I've a problem with my notebook DELL INSPIRON 1720.

This notebook have a CPU Intel t8100 **2.1GHz** and it doesn't work perfectly.

It works at 800MHz stable, like in power-safe. But when I change the performance mode, the CPU *remains* at 800MHz. Now the PC is *very* slow.

Comment: Does this happen when the notebook is plugged in to power?

Comment: Yes, it happens also when is plugged

Comment: solved by recompiling the kernel